# ORDER BY and = (equals) in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a question I came across an interesting piece of code. In MySQL statement there is something like:

> {...} ORDER BY whatever=3 ASC, whatever=4 ASC, whatever=6 ASC {...}

Does that mean that it will order in this way?:

```
thing | whatever  
15    | 1
1     | 3
5     | 3
8     | 3
2     | 4
3     | 4
6     | 4 
4     | 6
7     | 6
9     | 6
14    | 9
21    | 10
18    | 9 
...
```

It seems to be sorting only the whatever which equal to 3,4 and 6 rest is unordered...

Is this a proper/supported syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`whatever=3` evaluates as a boolean with `0` as false and `1` as `true`.

Because it is ordered ascending the ones not meeting the condition will be ordered first. Then the second ordering column `whatever=4` comes into play so ones where `whatever=4` will be last in that group and so on.

For ones where `whatever` is not in `(3,4,6)` no order is specified to act as a tiebreaker and ordering is arbitrary.

It is supported syntax in MySQL but not standard or portable.

Comment: `Because it is ordered ascending the ones not meeting the condition will be ordered first`?
Please elaborate why is it first? By ordered first do you mean appearing at top?

Comment: @GhazanfarMir Because if you sort the values `0` and `1` ascending. `0` comes first (yes, at the top).

Comment: I suppose they are jealous of your 67k and want you to robe of a few points. Your answer works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it orders by the result of comparison, which is boolean value of 0 or 1. The resulting code is something like (pseudo-code):

```
ORDER BY
   CASE whatever = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0
   ASC,
   CASE whatever = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0
   ASC
```

Which in the end comes to (if the value is in the list),

```
ORDER BY 0,0,1
ORDER BY 0,1,0
```

and if the value is not in the list:

```
ORDER BY 0,0,0
```

So values that are not in the list are considered with the same value and not ordered, and values in the list are ordered based on the position in the list.

You can replace this with `ORDER BY FIELD(whatever, 3,4,6)` ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field))